# Some examples for Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

I need some small examples for Lie algebras over finite fields ( GF(2) or GF(3))  including some simple Lie algebras and some others which are not simple. And I would be thankful if anyone could give the details for their basis and the matrices of adjoint representations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are examples of old and new simple Lie algebras over $GF(2)$ in the paper [Some new simple Lie algebras in characteristic 2](http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/~beick/publ/simlie.pdf) of Bettina Eick, in particular in section $5.4$, where explicit generators are given. In low dimensions there is the paper [Simple Lie algebras of low dimension](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJCM%2FJCM9%2FS1461157000001248a.pdf&code=ca55733843a27ec53592b187924f0996) of Michael Vaughan-Lee. As for non-simple ones, see the article [Classification of solvable Lie algebras](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404071) by Willem de Graaf.

Here is a $3$-dimensional example, the Jacobson-Witt Lie algebra $W(1,\underline{2})^{(1)}$ in characteristic $2$ with basis $x,y,h$ and Lie brackets $[x,y]=h,\;[h,x]=x,\;[h,y]=y$. Surely you know to to construct the adjoint operators from here:
$$
{\rm ad}(x)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \;
{\rm ad}(y)=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \;
{\rm ad}(h)=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \;
$$